# How to find two common coulmn in R

Tags: r

I have three diferent dataset named mus, dom and cas. They have same colnames including CRA, CHROM, POS, REF and ALT. I need to find the same REF and ALT values based on CHROM in each dataset. In another words I want to have REF and ALT values which is same in each one. for instance REF: A and ALT: T is found in all dataset and It may be in different CHROM, furthermore I need to keep other columns. How can I do that in R? please see below the format of samples. each sample named "cas", "dom" and "mus" has a different CRA and same CHROM, with different POS and REF and ALT. now I'd like to find same values of REF and ALT between these three samples based on CHROM ?

```html
CRA CHROM   POS REF ALT
dom_76  chr1    3365296 T   A
dom_76  chr1    3540134 T   C
dom_76  chr1    3665288 A   G
dom_76  chr1    7110674 T   C
dom_76  chr1    8920460 A   G
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can bind the datasets into a single data with `bind_rows`, while creating an id column (`.id`), then grouped by 'REF', 'ALT', 'CHROM', `filter` the rows where the number of distinct elements of 'grp' are 3 i.e. those are the ones having the common values in all the three datasets

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(cas, dom, mus, .id = 'grp') %>%
         group_by(REF, ALT, CHROM) %>%
         filter(n_distinct(grp) == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As CHROM is the same everywhere, there is no use keeping the column in the sort.
Otherwise, if I understand your question well, your are requesting a sort on a pair of variables. This can be done quickly using data.table as follows:

```
# Supposing the 3 samples are put together in the same CSV file
# with space separators

library(data.table)
DT <- fread("~/Documents/a.csv", sep=" ", header=TRUE)
setkey(DT, REF, ALT)
DT[.(REF, ALT), .(CRA, POS, REF, ALT)]

> DT[.(REF, ALT), .(CRA, POS, REF, ALT)]
      CRA     POS REF ALT
1: dom_76 3665288   A   G
2: dom_76 8920460   A   G
3: dom_76 3665288   A   G
4: dom_76 8920460   A   G
5: dom_76 3365296   T   A
6: dom_76 3540134   T   C
7: dom_76 7110674   T   C
8: dom_76 3540134   T   C
9: dom_76 7110674   T   C
```

If you still need the CHROM column for some reason, keep it in a "by" grouping:

```
> DT[.(REF, ALT), .(CRA, POS, REF, ALT), by="CHROM"]

CHROM    CRA     POS REF ALT
1:  chr1 dom_76 3665288   A   G
2:  chr1 dom_76 8920460   A   G
3:  chr1 dom_76 3665288   A   G
4:  chr1 dom_76 8920460   A   G
5:  chr1 dom_76 3365296   T   A
6:  chr1 dom_76 3540134   T   C
7:  chr1 dom_76 7110674   T   C
8:  chr1 dom_76 3540134   T   C
9:  chr1 dom_76 7110674   T   C
```

However your question is a bit ambiguous as "common" could be interpreted as "equal". I do not think this is what you requested but for completeness and just in case, below is the corresponding sort (empty in the posted data):

```
> DT[REF == ALT, .(CRA, POS, REF, ALT), by="CHROM"]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 4 cols): CRA,POS,REF,ALT
```

Comment: thank you for the response. but it didn't work for me. I've got the error  Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: This may occur if you have duplicates in your base. You should fliter out these duplucates: `DT<-data.table::unique(DT)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works properly. I used by=EACHI instead.

Comment: This may possibly avoid you duplicates, depending on your data structure, although it is not general. Also, you did by=.EACHI, mind the dot!

Comment: Excuse me, I need to filter common REF and ALT in the same position, so I added POS to filter it out, now I want to keep common REF and ALT and delete single SNPS like this one: 5:  chr1 dom_76 3365296   T   A. How can I do that? furthermore, I need to make a MDS plot between cas, mus and dom to show dispersal distance between them. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: This looks like a different isssue. To abide by SO rules, you should make a fresh post.